# Parsing URI parameter and keyword value pairs

Tags: python, parsing, url

I would like to parse the parameter and keyword values from URI/L's in a text file. Parameters without values should also be included. Python is fine but am open to suggestion using other tools such as Perl or a one-liner that may also do the trick.

Example source:

```
www.domain.com/folder/page.php?date=2012-11-20
www2.domain.edu/folder/folder/page.php?l=user&x=0&id=1&page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456&refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname&text=
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php?l=adm&y=5&id=2&page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp&unique=12345
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php?view=month&date=2011-12-10
```

Example output:

```
date=2012-11-20
l=user
x=0
page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456
refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
test=
l=adm
y=5
id=2
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
unique=12345
view=month
date=2011-12-10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to dive into fragile regex world.

[`urlparse.parse_qsl()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) is the tool for the job ([`urllib.quote()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) helps to escape special characters):

```
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import parse_qsl, urlparse


with open('links.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        params = parse_qsl(urlparse(url.strip()).query, keep_blank_values=True)
        for key, value in params:
            print "%s=%s" % (key, quote(value))
```

Prints:

```
date=2012-11-20
l=user
x=0
id=1
page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html
unique=123456
refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob%20test%201.21%20some%26file%3Dname
text=
l=adm
y=5
id=2
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
unique=12345
view=month
date=2011-12-10
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you use `parse_qsl` instead, you get a list instead of a dict.

Comment: @KirkStrauser thanks, the code looks better with `parse_qsl`.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a regular expression like this (first code then explanation):

```
pairs = re.findall(r'(\w+)=(.*?)(?:\n|&)', s, re.S)
for k, v in pairs:
    print('{0} = {1}'.format(k, v))
```

The first line is where the action happens. The regular expression finds all occurrences of a word followed by an equal sign and then a string that terminates either by a `&` or by a new line char. The return `pairs` is a tuple list, where each tuple contains the word (the keyword) and the value. I didn't capture the `=` sign, and instead I print it in the loop.

Explaining the regex:

`\w+` means one or more word chars. The parenthesis around it means to capture it and return that value as a result.

`=` - the equal sign that must follow the word

`.*?` - zero or more chars in a non-greedy manner, that is until a new line appears or the `&` sign, which is designated by `\n|&`. The `(?:..` pattern means that the `\n` or `&` should not be captured.

Since we capture 2 things in the regex - the keyword and everything after the `=` sign, a list of 2-tuples is returned.

The `re.S` tells the regex engine to allow the match-all regex code - `.` - include in the search the new line char as well, that is, allow the search span over multiple lines (which is not default behavior).

Comment: For almost any generally-useful function like this, you can assume it's already defined in the standard library. In this case, look in "urlparse" for a few alternatives that don't involve writing your own regexp.

Comment: Agreed. For the record: wasn't me.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment

Answer (score -2):

You can use a regular expression to extract all the pairs.

```
>>> url = 'www2.domain.edu/folder/folder/page.php?l=user&x=0&id=1&page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456&refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname&text='
>>> import re
>>> url = 'www2.domain.edu/folder/folder/page.php?l=user&x=0&id=1&page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456&refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname&text='
>>> p = re.compile('.*?&(.*?)=(.*?)(?=&|$)')
>>> m = p.findall(url)
>>> m
[('x', '0'), ('id', '1'), ('page', 'http%3A//domain.com/page.html'), ('unique', '123456'), ('refer', 'http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname'), ('text', '')]
```

You can even use a dict comprehension to package all the data together.

```
>>> dic = {k:v for k,v in m}
>>> dic
{'text': '', 'page': 'http%3A//domain.com/page.html', 'x': '0', 'unique': '123456', 'id': '1', 'refer': 'http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname'}
```

And then if all you want to do is print them out:

```
>>> for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    print k,'-->',v

text --> 
page --> http%3A//domain.com/page.html
x --> 0
unique --> 123456
id --> 1
refer --> http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
```

Comment: This doesn't unquote any of the values. But more importantly, `urlparse.parse_qs` does all of this for you.

Comment: An alternate solution that both works and ports more easily to other languages but doesn't use the magical url library...DOWNVOTE!

Comment: I downvoted because it doesn't actually work properly in the general case where you'd the output values to be the same as when they were originally input. There's an escape-unescape cycle that your solution ignores, so the output would be considered incorrect for most use cases.