# Group and Count unique string values and lengths

Tags: python

I would like to print the count of unique string values, length of characters, and the respective string. Python is fine but am open to suggestion using other tools. If a specific output is required, tab separated or similar that can be readily parsed would work. This is a followup to [Parsing URI parameter and keyword value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726136/parsing-uri-parameter-and-keyword-value-pairs).

Example source:

```
date=2012-11-20
test=
y=5
page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456
refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
test=
refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
y=5
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
view=month
y=5
y=5
y=5
```

Example output:

```
5   3  y=5
3  78  refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
2  52  page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
2  5   test=
1  15  date=2012-11-20
1  10  view=month
```

Here is an example where I was able to use a one-liner but assume it may be easier to come up with something in Python that can handle this and the length counting.

```
$ sort test | uniq -c | sort -nr
      5     y=5
      3     refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
      2     test=
      2     page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
      1     view=month
      1     page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456
      1     date=2012-11-20
```

Comment: Bearing in mind your previous answer that you're basing this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726136/parsing-uri-parameter-and-keyword-value-pairs is also in Python... It may have been useful to have provided a link to that question to provide context. As it wouldn't be inconceivable that you may wish to be doing this all in one process...

Comment: @JonClements This is a follow-up to that question but I came up with additional requirements. Updating question with link to original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it with Python. Usually people would tend to use dictionary to keep a track of duplicates

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> group = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open("test.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        group[len(line.rstrip())].append(line)
>>> for k, g in group.items():
    print k, len(g), g[0].strip()


3 5 y=5
5 2 test=
10 1 view=month
78 3 refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
15 1 date=2012-11-20
48 1 page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456
52 2 page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
```

Instead if you would like to mimic what you shell command, a similar thing can be achieved using `itertools.groupby`, which behaves similar to `uniq`

```
>>> with open("test.txt") as fin:
    file_it = (e.rstrip() for e in fin)
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(file_it, key = len), len):
        first_elem = next(g).strip()
        print k, sum(1 for _ in g) + 1, first_elem


3 5 y=5
5 2 test=
10 1 view=month
15 1 date=2012-11-20
48 1 page=http%3A//domain.com/page.html&unique=123456
52 2 page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
78 3 refer=http%3A//domain2.net/results.aspx%3Fq%3Dbob+test+1.21+some%26file%3Dname
```

Comment: Looking at your output, the length output seems to be incorrect starting from the second line? There seems to be an extra character being counted for every line item.

Comment: @Aston: The newline was adding an extra character, I have updated the answer to reflect the newline consideration.