# Group values with common domain and page values

Tags: python, url

Based on a follow-up from a previous question [Parsing URI parameter and keyword value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726136/parsing-uri-parameter-and-keyword-value-pairs), I would like to group URLs that have the same domain and page name, followed by all of the parameter and values. The URLs may have the same or a different number of parameters and/or respective values. The URL/page value is printed, followed by all of it parameter and keyword values.

I am looking for an answer using Python to parse, group and print the values. I have not been able to find an answer via Google or SO.

Example source of URLs with various parameters and values:

```
www.domain.com/page?id_eve=479989&adm=no
www.domain.com/page?id_eve=47&adm=yes
www.domain.com/page?id_eve=479
domain.com/cal?view=month
domain.com/cal?view=day
ww2.domain.com/cal?date=2007-04-14
ww2.domain.com/cal?date=2007-08-19
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php?l=adm&y=5&id=2&page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp&unique=12345
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php?view=day&date=2011-12-10
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php?l=adm&y=5&id=2&page=http%3A//.domain.com/downloads/index.asp&unique=12345
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php?view=month&date=2011-12-10
```

Example output I am looking for. The URL and a list of the parameter/value combinations from all of the URLs that are the same is the original.

```
www.domain.com/page
id_eve=479989
id_eve=47
id_eve=479
adm=no
adm=yes
domain.com/cal
view=month
view=day
w2.domain.com/cal
date=2007-04-14
date=2007-08-19
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php
l=adm
l-adm
id=2
id=2
page=http%3A//.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defaultdict()` to collect parameters per url path:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import parse_qsl, urlparse


urls = defaultdict(list)
with open('links.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        parsed_url = urlparse(url.strip())
        params = parse_qsl(parsed_url.query, keep_blank_values=True)
        for key, value in params:
            urls[parsed_url.path].append("%s=%s" % (key, quote(value)))

# printing results
for url, params in urls.iteritems():
    print url
    for param in params:
        print param
```

prints:

```
ww2.domain.com/cal
date=2007-04-14
date=2007-08-19
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php
l=adm
y=5
id=2
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
unique=12345
l=adm
y=5
id=2
page=http%3A//.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
unique=12345
domain.com/cal
view=month
view=day
www.domain.com/page
id_eve=479989
adm=no
id_eve=47
adm=yes
id_eve=479
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php
view=day
date=2011-12-10
view=month
date=2011-12-10
```

Hope that helps.