# Determing variance in length

Tags: python

I am trying to determine the variance in length of parameter values and print the variance value after the set of respective parameter/value combinations.

For example, the value of variance of `date` in `date=2007-04-14` and `date=2007-08-19` would be 0. The value of `id_eve` in `id_eve=479989`, `id_eve=47`, and `id_eve=479` would be 2.88.

From [Group values with common domain and page values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880717/group-values-with-common-domain-and-page-values), we have a set of URLs which are parsed to provide the parameter/values for a set of URLs.

Sample data-set:

```
www.domain.com/page?id_eve=479989&adm=no
www.domain.com/page?id_eve=47&adm=yes
www.domain.com/page?id_eve=479
domain.com/cal?view=month
domain.com/cal?view=day
ww2.domain.com/cal?date=2007-04-14
ww2.domain.com/cal?date=2007-08-19
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php?l=adm&y=5&id=2&page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp&unique=12345
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php?view=day&date=2011-12-10
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php?l=adm&y=5&id=2&page=http%3A//.domain.com/downloads/index.asp&unique=12345
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php?view=month&date=2011-12-10
```

Is parsed by the following Python code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import parse_qsl, urlparse

urls = defaultdict(list)
with open('links.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        parsed_url = urlparse(url.strip())
        params = parse_qsl(parsed_url.query, keep_blank_values=True)
        for key, value in params:
            urls[parsed_url.path].append("%s=%s" % (key, quote(value)))

# printing results
for url, params in urls.iteritems():
    print url
    for param in params:
        print param
```

To provide:

```
ww2.domain.com/cal
date=2007-04-14
date=2007-08-19
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php
l=adm
y=5
id=2
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
unique=12345
l=adm
y=5
id=2
page=http%3A//.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
unique=12345
domain.com/cal
view=month
view=day
www.domain.com/page
id_eve=479989
adm=no
id_eve=47
adm=yes
id_eve=479
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php
view=day
date=2011-12-10
view=month
date=2011-12-10
```

The additional piece needed is for every parameter/value combination to print the variation in length of the parameter values for matching parameters with a similar URL as defined in the above output (hope that read clearly).

- Group parameters for grouping of urls
- Calculate lengths of parameter values
- Determine variation of length

So the desired output would be:

```
ww2.domain.com/cal
date=2007-04-14
date=2007-08-19
0
www.domain.edu/some/folder/image.php
l=adm
l=adm
0
y=5
y=5
0
id=2
id=2
0
page=http%3A//support.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
0
unique=12345
0      
page=http%3A//.domain.com/downloads/index.asp
unique=12345
0
domain.com/cal
0
view=month
view=day
1
www.domain.com/page
id_eve=479989
id_eve=47
id_eve=479
2.88
adm=no
adm=yes
0.25
blog.news.org/news/calendar.php
view=day
view=month
1
date=2011-12-10
date=2011-12-10
0
```

Comment: Can you explain why your example would be 2.88 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import parse_qsl, urlparse
```

We need to be able to calculate variance:

```
def variance(values):
    mean = sum(values) / float(len(values))
    return sum((elem - mean)**2 for elem in values) / float(len(values))
```

We want to group by "key", so instead of putting `"%s=%s"` we're going to add another layer to the `defaultdict`.

```
urls = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
with open('links.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        parsed_url = urlparse(url.strip())
        params = parse_qsl(parsed_url.query, keep_blank_values=True)
        for key, value in params:
            urls[parsed_url.path][key].append(quote(value))
```

Then we can just go through and print stuff

```
for domain, keys in urls.items():
    print domain
    for key, values in keys.items():
        for value in values:
            print "%s=%s" % (key, value)

        if len(values) > 1:
            print variance(map(len, values))
```